# MySQL Update Value from SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm using MySQL and am running a query, which I think should work, but apparently I'm missing something.

0 records get updated when I run:

```
UPDATE `client` 
  SET StatementTermsID = (SELECT StatementTermsID FROM statementterms WHERE TermsDescription = 'NET 15') 
  WHERE `client`.StatementNote LIKE '%Net 15%';
```

If I run the subquery by itself, I get the record id as expected. If I change the subquery to be a static value, then 2000 plus records get updated. Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different syntax:

```
UPDATE `client` a,
(SELECT StatementTermsID FROM statementterms WHERE TermsDescription = 'NET 15') b
SET a.StatementTermsID = b.StatementTermsID
WHERE a.StatementNote LIKE '%Net 15%';
```

Comment: I used this and it also updated 0 rows... any ideas?

Comment: @VenomFangs, perhaps because they were updated earlier?

Comment: Yes, just got another developer to give me a sanity check and the statements worked... the original query seemed to work too. I'll delete the question... as it was a PEBKAC

Answer (score 1):

i Think you should use a join. I can see that we cannot use StatementTermsID because thats what you are trying to update.So for sure it won`t be there in the former table.
If you have any ids to join Use that as well.

```
UPDATE client
SET StatementTermsID =statementterms.StatementTermsID 
FROM client
INNER JOIN statementterms 
   WHERE statementterms.TermsDescription = 'NET 15' AND 
   client.StatementNote LIKE '%Net 15%';
```

Or else Try this syntax

```
UPDATE client , statementterms 
   SET client.StatementTermsID = statementterms .StatementTermsID 
 WHERE statementterms.TermsDescription = 'NET 15' AND 
       client.StatementNote LIKE '%Net 15%';
```

Comment: doesn't like the "from" in your statement

Comment: do u have any id`s to join?

Comment: @VenomFangs:: I have updated with a different syntax

Comment: nothing to join off of, this update is trying to create that link from non normalized data :)

Comment: i was a little skeptical to answer this because with out a common id the mysql can never identify what we are referring to.Logically,The 0 rows updated is an expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55463/discussion-between-venomfangs-and-vjhil).